# TlbExp.exe error:This assembly is built by a runtime newer

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, tlbexp

We are moving part of our server to .net 4.0. We already did the move to Vs2010 as a first step but did not change the target framework of any project.

As a second step I'm moving a specific part of our server to target 4.0 so we can use some of the new functionality.

I've run into a problem when calling TLBexp.exe on a Class library DLL that targets 4.0. This DLL also references a lot of DLLs that target 2.0.

I get the error: TlbExp : error TX0000: Could not load file or assembly 'file:Library.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

I am calling the TLBExp that comes with: Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\
In the command I call in the VS2010 command prompt I reference v4.0.30319 binaries (such as mscorlib.tlb)

Is running TLB on a 4.0 DLL that references 2.0 libraries allowed?
If yes then any reason why I'm getting this error.

Here is the exact command call i use: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\tlbexp.exe" /silent /win32 /tlbreference:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb" /tlbreference:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.tlb" /tlbreference:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Windows.Forms.tlb" /tlbreference:"C:\Windows\system32\stdole2.tlb" C:\Dev\Library.dll

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had an assembly targeting 4.0, that referenced another assembly which had a target framework of 3.5.

As a result, I was getting the same error on a "post build" step.  By trial and error, I discovered that the version of TLBExp found in this folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\` could generate the TLB file successfully.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew. Works when using the other TLBExp. I would vote your answer up but I need 15 to vote up.

Comment: Thanks. + 1 I just found this and it got me one step closer in a project I'm working on - or maybe just one step deeper into the thicket :).

Comment: Use %ProgramFiles% for cross-bitness.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following path to TlbExp, which will be picked up automatically based on project framework version:

```
$(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)\tlbexp.exe
```

Comment: +1: Actually, this is a very good reminder about VisualStudio's variables/macros. In PreBuild/PostBuild steps visible, there's a "Macros" button that presents only a tiny part of the variables available. They all come from the MSBuild layer, and there are **tons** of them. Mostly usable when tailoring .csprojs by hand, but in Pre/PostBuild step, they are nicely expanded too.