# How do I get .NET 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I looked up Microsoft .NET 4.0 and I downloaded 2 things. the web installer and client profile but according to the bottom of this picture, I don't have it.

[image: Screenshot of error]

The error message is:

> Could not load file or assembly `App_Code` or one of dependencies. This assembly is bui;t by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Comment: 1) This looks like ASP.net, so client profile won't be enough 2) It's possible that you have .net 4 installed, but the used runtime is still 2.0.

Comment: Read the bottom line of the error message: the App Pool is running .NET 2 CLI (ie. V2, V3 or V3.5 framework).

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked the value of the **'.NET Framework Version'** column for your Application Pool via IIS?

[image: Application Pool Config]

To change this:

1. Open IIS Click on the 'Application Pools' level within the tree
   structure you see on the left hand side of the application
2. Right click on your application pool in the list and select 'Basic
   Settings'
3. Change the value of the 'Net framework version' to be v4.0
4. Press 'OK' for the changes to be applied and the app pool will
   recycle ready for use

Comment: Can you tell me step by step how to do that?

Comment: @James I've updated my post with some basic steps on how to do it :)

Answer (score 2):

An existing web application will continue to run .net 2.0 since the frameworks are installed side-by-side. You have to explicitly configure the app pool to run 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your application pool in IIS (I assume you're using IIS) is set to .NET 4.0 (it sets itself to 2.0 by default).  Failing that you could always try re-registering .NET with IIS:

1. Open command prompt
2. Enter the following: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
3. Press enter

Answer (score 0):

1st  [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607095/this-assembly-is-built-by-a-runtime-newer-than-the-currently-loaded-runtime-and).

2nd [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138735/error-this-assembly-is-built-by-a-runtime-newer-than-the-currently-loaded-runti)

And Make sure your IIS application pool is set to .NET 4.0, for help regarding that.. Check this.

[MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx)