# Add 4.5 project inside a solution with 4.0 projects

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

Can I add a 4.5 project inside a solution with only 4.0 projects?

Example:

```
-ProductSolution
   -Product.Domain.csproj (4.0)
   -Product.Web.csproj (4.0)
   -Product.WebApi.csproj (4.5)
```

I can't migrate my projects right now. And I want to add an Web Api and reference it to my Product.Domain project.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have projects with  multiple .Net versions in a single solution under Visual Studio,

**BUT**, you can't refer a .Net framework 4.5 version project inside an older version's project.

[.Net frameworks are not forward compatible.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807351/reference-a-net-framework-4-5-1-assembly-in-a-4-0-project)

So your project `Product.WebApi.csproj (4.5)` is based on 4.5, you can't add reference to it in `Product.Domain.csproj (4.0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't. A 4.0 project can't reference a 4.5 project so the end goal is unachievable.

Comment: It's the inverse man. A 4.5 project will reference a 4.0 proj.

Comment: I would now delete this answer except for wallybh's comment. That makes two of us who got it backwards.