# Build warning Modeling Project with .NET 4.6 Class

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

Working on a project running Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6. I have a modeling project and a class project.  The class project is targeting .NET 4.6, when I add the class project to the modeling project as a Layer Reference.  I get the following warning message:

> ------ Build started: Project: Plataforma.Architecture, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1811,5): warning MSB3274: The primary reference "C:\Projects\Test\bin\Debug\Utilities.dll" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1".
>
> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

How do you upgrade a modeling project to the latest version of the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the .NET version differs, this seems to be a duplicate of [Reference a .net framework 4.5.1 assembly in a 4.0 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807351/reference-a-net-framework-4-5-1-assembly-in-a-4-0-project)

Probably caused by the in-place upgrade from .NET 4.5.1 to .NET 4.6

Comment: Seems as if the modeling projects in VS 2015 is still .NET 4.5.1.  Hopefully when it reaches production it will all be the same .NET version.